# Confronting climate challenges is mission critical

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "mission critical" following the linguistic pattern of "Mission Impossible" the title of a famous film? It seems to me that if expressed in routine English, it should have been "a critical mission." But "Mission Critical" sounds much more sensitive and stronger.

The question of this thread is whether "mission critical" is a mimic of "Mission Impossible" (the title of the film) or it is historical in popular use in English (the film is not its origin etymologically).

> Deputy Secretary of Defense Dr. Kathleen Hicks tweeted:
>
> Joined @DeptofDefense leaders today for our 1st Climate Working Group. **Confronting climate challenges is mission critical.** New demands on the force impact readiness.

Comment: This should answer your question:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mission+critical&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmission%20critical%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmission%20critical%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Mission critical" is software engineering jargon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. **The question of this thread is whether "mission critical" is a mimic of "Mission Impossible" (the title of the film) or it is historical in popular use in English (the film is not its origin etymologically).**

**I would answer No** IT IS NOT RELATED TO THE FILM.

---

Mission critical is quite common language, however it is commonly misused.

Mission critical is a component that is a critical part of a mission not a "Critical
Mission"

---

### However "mission-critical" is what I think she intended to use

**mission-critical;** adjective; extremely important or necessary for a company, activity, etc. to operate successfully:

Example of use

They should not, therefore, be central to any **mission-critical application** given that they may not predict the right control given a particular situation.

[Cambridge English Dictionary; mission-critical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mission-critical)

**Note;** I am aware that "mission-critical" exists in an un-hyphenated form in some online dictionaries. However it does not exist in a two word format, be it hyphenated or not, In MERRIAM-WEBSTER'S as far as I can ascertain. It does however appear in The CED.

Comment: In my opinion the inclusion of the hyphen is important, as it helps to reduce the impression of critical mission.( Mission, critical)

Comment: I would agree. I think the phrase "this is mission-critical" is really an abbreviation of the more correct phrase "this is *a mission-critical [noun]*," which is where the hyphen comes from.

Comment: @Brad: Thank you.  What does CED stand for? Center for Educational Documentation?

Comment: @NewPlanet: Cambridge English Dictionary

Answer (score -1):

Using mission critical isn't the same as mission impossible because mission impossible is the idea the mission can't be fulfilled, while mission critical is the idea that it's a very important assignment.